# RRAS vs. Open VPN

Tags: windows, centos, vpn, openvpn, rras

Performance wise, which is better, RRAS or OpenVPN?

I'm thinking of moving to a new server but if I do, then I'll have to ditch RRAS, and switch to OpenVPN.. So back to my original question "Performance wise, which is better, RRAS or OpenVPN? "

Comment: It seems to me like the biggest performance difference is related to the encryption algorithms used, but in both cases that can be configured to some extent.

Answer (score 4):

Performance for any VPN solution is typically limited by the available bandwidth between the clients and the termination point. Unless you have an extraordinarily large pipe and a significant amount of remote users (thousands), it's not going to make a difference. And if you do have that volume, you should look at load-balanced VPN concentrators rather than a single server.

The difference is in what features each solution supports and how it handles tunnel management, remote route pushing, etc.